# Update a field in a sql table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in my database that has the fields id, state, number and date.

What I need is to update the state of the record that matches the id that comes as a parameter.

I am doing the following but there is no result:

```
static public function mdlUpdateField($table, $id){

    $stmt = Conection::conect()->prepare("UPDATE $table SET state = :state WHERE id = :id");

    $stmt->bindParam(":state", "OK", PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt -> execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error"; 

    }

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;

}
```

When I do it, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: You didn't bind :id with your value.

Comment: @TobiasHH Could you post what you should do? I have basic knowledge. And in passing I give you as the correct answer, if it is.

Comment: Just see what scaisEdge answered :)
If your variable $id isn't an integer, change PDO::PARAM_INT to PDO::PARAM_STR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt->bindParam(":state", "OK", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

and for pass  the tale name you need dinamic sql

```
("UPDATE " . $table . " SET state = :state WHERE id = :id");
```

In this way you are at risk for sqlinjection  ..

Comment: I have done what you told me, but the error persists. Moreover, I have defined the variable that arrives as an $ id = 1, to verify that it works with a record of my table, and the error remains the same

Comment: answer  updated .. you are also using php var for pass  object name (table name)  .. this  is dangerous for sql inject  ..